# ndb_index_stat_enable = OFF in old legacy mysql 5.1.51

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have **ndb_index_stat_enable = OFF** setting in a legacy mysql version 5.1.51.

This means statistics are never updated automatically ?

(I am trying to find out why mysql choosing a bad index in many queries. By bad-index i mean being able to choose between 2 indexes, mysql chooses the one that returns more rows)

Comment: You might be better served by posting a question about the specific problem you're having, with table definitions and `EXPLAIN SELECT` output, either here or on sister site http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have added the question to dba stack exchange as you suggested http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105475/mysql-query-choosing-the-incorrect-plan with more data and detailed explain plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global variable [`ndb_index_stat_enable`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-system-variables.html) is only applicable to MySQL NDB Cluster Server.  It's present in Standard MySQL Server but has no effect.